# How can you attack or redirect the client from the server over an RDP or SSH conneciton?

Tags: ssh, ports, rdp, tunneling

I have a penetration testing scenario where I am on the network with two machines, Machine A and Machine B. I have complete control over Machine B and am trying to leverage that to get access to Machine A. Machine A appears to be some variant of Linux (I pinged it and the response had a TTL value of 64, but I know this could be spoofed which is why it is only my guess), and Machine B is Ubuntu Linux.

An nmap scan of Machine A found that port 443 was open and port 22 was filtered. I have drawn the conclusion that Machine A accepts SSH connections via port 22, but behind some rule or firewall.

Machine A acts as a bastion, so the web application on port 443 (which I have already tested for vulnerabilities and found none) lets authenticated users have an interactive RDP or SSH session with machines on the network, from the context of Machine A. So I can log into the web application that Machine A is hosting and connect via a browser over to Machine B via RDP or SSH.

Because I have full control over Machine B and can get Machine A to connect to it, what RDP or SSH attacks are there that I can leverage? I am thinking primarily of whether or not there's a way to have Machine B make Machine A redirect the session to localhost, which would mean Machine A would connect back to itself over SSH in a session I can interact with.

Note: I am aware of SSH reverse tunneling, but that requires special configuration on Machine A's side when the connection is established, and I don't have access to that.

Comment: Do ***NOT*** create new accounts to answer your own questions

Comment: Why did you delete the question then copy/paste it into a new post?

Comment: I didn't think it should be closed, I thought people were misreading the question so I wanted to make some clarifications.

Comment: Right. Do not delete and repost closed questions without addressing the reasons why it was closed in the first place. Edit the question to add the requested details. What clarifications? It's identical.

Comment: The problem with the question is that it is too open-ended. You do not have a specific goal in mind, and you look like you are trying to gather different options. The one thing that's not clear is why you can't simply SSH into Machine A from Machine A. Is that an option? If so, then your proposal to ARP poison won't work either. There's just too many unknowns in your situation and your question might have too many possible answers.

Comment: I can only RDP or SSH into a few machines from Machine A, Machine A is not one of them. But I can RDP/SSH into Machine B from Machine A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to directly attack the client from the server in that way, but here's what I managed to do, in case anyone else finds it helpful. I used ARP poisoning to make the IP address of Machine B point to the MAC address of Machine A. That way, when I logged on to the web interface and connected to Machine B, it actually resolved to Machine A.